# What is the difference between server side scripting and network programing ? What purpose does network programing serve?

Tags: network-programming, server-side-scripting

I actually started node.js but i don't know how it is different from network programming.

Answer (score 0):

in CS, you are doing network programming when you are  creating softwares that communicates through computer network using sockets, protocols, etc.

Doing node.js is just as you mentioned "server side scripting" because you are not involved with sockets or communication with the client browser or anything else. You are just *exploiting* the network mechanics / softwares.

There are huge differences between the functions you call in C such as `socket()`, `connect()` and `accept()` and your node.js stuff.

Take a look to the man pages of these functions. You will understand.